# Get file contents after pageload

Tags: php, mime-types, file-get-contents

I have an external resource for my images let's say `https://api.domain.com/api/downloads/{file_id}`. The file gets downloaded after I visit that page. In this case I want to know the mimetype of the file. `file_get_contents()` doesn't work because the file is downloaded after I visit the page.

This means that I get HTML as output when I dump the result of `file_get_contents()`. I don't have any hold on how images are served to my application. So I guess I have to find a solution for this problem.

Is there a way to get the mimetype of a file after the page is loaded and it downloaded the file? If something I just wrote is not clear enough please let me know then I try to explain it further. Thanks in advance.

**Some more detailed information:**

I am currently creating an EML export from data from an external API from Genesys. This is pure PHP and thus I can’t make use of any client-side code like Javascript. The inline images in the body don’t show on in the EML export email body. I think this is because Genesys saves those images somewhere on their side. The image is not directly available from the URL they gave to me, because when I visit that page the page downloads a file but it is not directly served on that page.

To show the images inside the email body I want to encode them to base64 and change the src of the image to the base64 encoded image. To do so I need to know the filetype which I can’t get as described above.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try with the onload property on the `<img />` tag ?

```
<img src="w3html.gif" onload="loadImage()" width="100" height="132">

<script>
function loadImage() {
    alert("Image is loaded");
}
</script>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp

You will need to use javascript as the image is on a remote server and loaded on client side

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Javascript. I have added some more explanation in my question.